# Retrieve data values from specific mysql table column and print in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve all values from the column `country_name` and table `ban_country_ip` and after print them:

```
<?php
 include("config.inc.php");
 $countryiso = mysql_query("SELECT distinct(country_name) as country_name FROM ban_country_ip");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countryiso)) {
 echo $row['country_name'];
}
```

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct is not a function in mysql, use following query instead

```
"SELECT distinct country_name FROM ban_country_ip"
```